# Protect API Calls From Android App

Tags: android, api, security, rest

I built a restful API and we secured the calls by app id & app secret. But as we know reverse engineering for android apps is a pretty easy task so any one can do that and make calls using these secrets.

**My Question: What is the best way to protect api calls from android app?**

**And way and google use package name and hashes, is it related to the security i am taking about?**

Comment: If your API/site will support user logins, you can use OAuth and the server can provide JWT tokens for communicating with the API. If not, you can look into deploying a simple Attestation Service, and using an Attestation library in your mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you hardcoding that stuff? You can make a login screen and send the info from it to the server. Then the server performs identification and sends to you a session token (which, in addition, can be valid for a certain period of time only).
In general, we have to assume that what can be hacked has been hacked.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer, we are doing this for calls that needs user authentication. but the problem for calls that doesn't require any authentication like search, get item details. There are some hackers trying to get all of our catalog daily (using our keys) and for that we need to protect our calls.

Comment: I am wondering why facebook and google maps for example are using the package name and the key store to identify android apps?